# Не работает If Else в jq с hide show

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.zubr').click(function(){
      var show = $('.mobile-head');
        if(show.css('display', 'none')){
            show.show('1000')
        }
        else{
            show.hide('1000')
        }


    })
});
```

```css
.mobile-head{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobile-head">z</div>
<button class="zubr">Click me</button>
```

Не работает обычная анимация, кнопка и сам блок, блок при нажатии должен скрываться если он показан, и показываться если скрыт. Но работает только 1 условие. 
Почему?

Comment: JavaScript работает так как надо. У вас условие неправильно написано...Что вы хотите проверить? может вы имели в виду `if ( show.css('display') == 'none' ) { } `

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, лучше так:

```js
$('.zubr').click(function(){
  var show = $('.mobile-head');
  if(!show.hasClass('show')){
    show.addClass('show');
    show.show('1000');
  } else {
    show.removeClass('show');
    show.hide('1000')
  }

});
```

```css
.mobile-head{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<div class="mobile-head">z</div>
<button class="zubr">Click me</button>
```

Или так:

```js
$('.zubr').click(function(){
  var show = $('.mobile-head');
  show.slideToggle();

});
```

```css
.mobile-head{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<div class="mobile-head">z</div>
<button class="zubr">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Что Вы думаете возвращает `show.css( , )` в

```
if(show.css('display', 'none')){
```

Оно возвращает jQuery-евский объект `show`, что в булевском смысле означает `true`.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
if (show.css('display') == 'none') {
  show.show('1000');
} else {
  show.hide('1000');
}
```

или

```
if (show.css('display') != 'none') {
  show.hide('1000');
} else {
  show.show('1000');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить является ли элемент видимым, у jQuery есть специальная конструкция

```
if (show.is(':visible'))
```

но так как Вам нужно всего лишь поменять статус видимости на противоположный, то для этого Вам достаточно использовать метод `toggle()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.zubr').click(function(){
      $('.mobile-head').toggle(1000);
    })
});
```

```css
.mobile-head{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobile-head">z</div>
<button class="zubr">Click me</button>
```